# Open local folder from link

Tags: javascript, html

How can I open a local folder view by clicking on any link?

I tried many options like

`<a href="file:///D:/Tools/">Open folder</a>` or

`<a onclick="file:///D:/Tools/">Open folder</a>` or

`<a onclick="window.open(file:///D:/Tools/)">Open folder</a>`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Linking to local resources is disabled in all modern browsers due to security restrictions.

For [Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_Issues_:_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don%27t_Work):

> For security purposes, Mozilla applications block links to local files (and directories) from remote files. This includes linking to files on your hard drive, on mapped network drives, and accessible via Uniform Naming Convention (UNC) paths. This prevents a number of unpleasant possibilities, including:
>
> - Allowing sites to detect your operating system by checking default installation paths
> - Allowing sites to exploit system vulnerabilities (e.g., C:\con\con in Windows 95/98)
> - Allowing sites to detect browser preferences or read sensitive data

for [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Internet Explorer 6 Service Pack 1 (SP1) no longer allows browsing a local machine from the Internet zone. For instance, if an Internet site contains a link to a local file, Internet Explorer 6 SP1 displays a blank page when a user clicks on the link. Previous versions of Windows Internet Explorer followed the link to the local file.

for [Opera](http://www.opera.com/support/kb/view/896/) (in the context of a security advisory, I'm sure there is a more canonical link for this):

> As a security precaution, Opera does not allow Web pages to link to files on the user's local disk

Comment: But I can browse the local files and directories in Mozilla and IE via "file:///D:/Tools/" in URL . I use Mozilla 3.6 and IE 8. If I use the same URL for anchor tags, it does not open up the files and folders

Comment: @Satya yup, that's exactly the way the security mechanism is supposed to work - to prevent malicious linking from remote sites

Comment: @Odelya I don't know a definitive source but from experience, Chrome's handling of local resources is as strict as Firefox's.

Answer (score 48):

### Solution: Launching a Downloadable Link

The following works in all browsers, but as always there are caveats.

**Background:**

"URL Shortcuts" are OS dependent.  The following solution is for MS Windows due to a lack of standards between environments.

If you require linux support for the solution below, please see this [article](http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2009/12/09/how-to-open-url-internet-explorer-shortcuts-in-ubuntu-using-firefox/).
* I have no connection to the article, YMMV.

URL shortcuts come in two forms:

1. Files with .URL extensions are text based.  Can be dynamically generated.

   > [InternetShortcut]
   >   URL=file:///D:/
2. Files with .LNK extension are binary. They can be generated dynamically, but require iShelLinkInterface implementer.  This is complicated by default OS restrictions, which rightfully prevent an IIS process from reaching Shell.

.URL is the recommended solution, as dynamic generation is viable across Web Languages/Frameworks and allows for a KISS implementation.

---

**Overview/Recap:**

1. Security restrictions will not allow you to open a path/launch explorer directly from the page (as stated by @Pekka).
2. Sites hosted externally (not on your local computer) will not allow file:///... uri's under default security permissions.

---

**Solution:**

Provide a downloadable link (.URL or .LNK) to the resource.  Browser behavior will be explained at end of post.

 **Option 1:** Produce a .lnk file and save it to the server. Due to the binary nature of the .LNK file, this is not the recommended solution, but a pre-generated file should be viable.

 **Option 2:** Produce a .url file and either save it to the server or dynamically generate
    it. In my situation, I am dynamically creating the .URL file.

---

**Solution Details (.URL):**

1. Add .url to the available MIME types in your web server.

   For IIS open the site, choose MIME Types, and add the following:

   > File name Extension= .url
   >   MIME type: application/internet-shortcut

   Per @cremax ...
   For Webkit Browsers like Chrome on Apache Servers add this code to .htaccess or http.config:

   > SetEnvIf Request_URI ".url$" requested_url=url Header add Content-Disposition "attachment" env=requested_url
2. The .url file is a text file formatted as follows (again, this can be dynamically generated).

   File Contents:

   > [InternetShortcut]
   >   URL=file:///D:
3. Provide a link to the script that generates the .url file, or to the file itself.

   If you've simply uploaded a .url file to your server, add the following to your HTML:

   `<a href="URIShortcut.url">Round-About Linking</a>`

---

**Browser Dependent Behavior**

*Chrome*:  Download/Save file.url then open
  In Chrome, this behavior can be augmented by choosing the "Always open files of this type" option.

*FireFox*:  Download/Save file.url then open

*Internet Explorer*:  Click “Open” and go straight to directory (no need to save shortcut)

> Internet Explorer has the preferred behavior, but Chrome and Firefox
>   are at least serviceable.

Comment: It should be noted with the [InternetShortcut] option that once it gives you the option to download or save it, your browser can't tell that you already have the file and it will be duplicated in your temp directory, so beware of doing this with large files.

Comment: @MrLore is correct.  Ideally the shortcut should not be retained (that is, the end user should be unaware of the need to delete the downloaded link.)  The only way I know to accomplish this is via IE's behavior of saving to IETemp and allow the user to select open/run on download (vs. save).  I'll post back if I ever revisit this and am able to come up with something better.

Comment: I just stumbled across this solution but I find that my browser simply opens the .url file and displays its text. I'm on XAMPP, locally. Do I need to somehow tell XAMPP to interpret these .url files differently?

Comment: Hi @Utkanos, It may either be the way Apache is encoding/sending the file or the browser's file association.  Did you try cremax's instructions for configuring Apache?  PS: Use the @ symbol + name and the person will be notified of your message.

Comment: This worked for me, "SetEnvIf Request_URI ".url$" requested_url=url Header add Content-Disposition "attachment" env=requested_url" was what I needed to get it to work in Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

Only IE6-8 - there's an ActiveX workaround this local-files issue in JavaScript:

```
        function OpenImage(filePath)
        {
            var myshell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
            myshell.run(filePath, 1, true); 
        }
```

Comment: -1: Doesn't work well if ActiveX is disabled (which is is, in most instances).

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I have seen this functionality implemented in many Intranet web applications, with appropriate configurations for Local-Intranet for specific websites (like [http: //coName-net ])

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
<a href="\\computername\folder">Open folder</a>
```

in Internet Explorer

Answer (score 2):

add on click open local directory o local file to google chrome:

The solution from JFish222 works ( URL file solution )

For Webkid Browsers like Chrome on Apache Servers just add to .htaccess o http.config this code:

SetEnvIf Request_URI ".url$" requested_url=url
Header add Content-Disposition "attachment" env=requested_url

And by the first downlod of your url file click on the file in chromes downloadbar and select "always open this file".

Answer (score -2):

**Local Explorer** - File Manager on web browser extention  can solve  for chrome

but still some encoding problems

Comment: The question is specifically focusing on using JavaScript and HTML to open local folders, not using extensions.

Answer (score -3):

URL Specifies the URL of the document to embed in the iframe.
Possible values:

An absolute URL - points to another web site (like src="http://www.example.com/default.htm")
A relative URL - points to a file within a web site (like src="default.htm")