# I cannot display an image with an absolue path :

Tags: html, xhtml

here is my code, why cant i disaply this image :

```
<img src="file:///C:/Users/myname/Documents/WWWDIR/resources/files/users/logo.jpg" alt="photo2" border="0"/>
```

i see only the alt text, but i am able to see the image in firebug.
any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is from a remote (`http://`) page, it is by design: You can't link to local resources from remote pages in modern browsers any more. See details for each browser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246292/open-local-folder-from-link/5246334#5246334).