# Anchor tag with link to internal file (file:///) is not working in any browser

Tags: html, anchor

I have a HTML file in my site with a sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>This is a test for internal files </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <A  href="file:///networkpath/folderName/File Name.pdf" target=_blank>click here</A>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I tried all possible combination of slashes (forward/backward) but nothing seems to work in IE and FF. The link is dead, no action at all.

When I save the same file in my local machine it work fine. Same file When I copied to a internet site it didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open local folder from link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246292/open-local-folder-from-link)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Same file When I copied to a internet site it dint work.

This is by design. All modern browsers prevent linking to local resources for security reasons.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246292/open-local-folder-from-link/5246334#5246334) for details.

Comment: Thank you...is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Akila not really, no. It may be possible to make this work for specific browsers on a PC using some browser settings, but I don't know whether that is true and if yes, which ones

Answer (score 1):

It works only if you add your url (website adderess) in "Trusted Site" list.

Here how to do it in for IE:

- Go to **Tools > Internet Options > Security > Trusted Site**
- Add your URL