# Opening a specific folder (windows explorer) from HTML URL

Tags: url, asp-classic, directory, explorer

I am in the process of building the internal site (ASP) for a website that handles applications for mortgate loans.

For each application, there's a folder on the server that contains unique attatchments linked to the application. A wide spread of formats for the attatchments leads to my boss asking me to simply make a link that opens said attatchment-folder per application.

Using file://servername/foldername/ works, but it takes AGES after clicking it before the actual folder opens. Any more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If these folders on your server are within the root of your web-application you could enable directory-browsing on those folders. This will make IIS show you all files within if you navigate to that folder.
http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc731109(v=ws.10).aspx

If they are outside your web-root, you can still do this- you can add those folders as virtual folders to IIS. But in that case you will have to give the Anonymous Internet user read rights to those folders.
http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc771004(v=ws.10).aspx

If you need to both read and write to these folders, you could look into the WebDAV protocol, which can be installed on IIS. This allows you to use certain folders as a special kind of networked drive. It allows reading and writing over the http(s) protocol.
http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-webdav-on-iis

HTH,
Erik

Answer (score 0):

@Rico has hit a number of bases.  Directory browsing is an excellent solution if you only need to read the files.

If you also want to allow file editing, WebDav is also a possible solution, but I may be able to recommend something easier:

Please see my response ["Launching a Downloadable Link"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14249649/1195927) to a similar question.  Though the user was asking about a file and not a complete directory, this solution will work with either.

The premise is a downloadable *.url file.  This will prevent issues if the user is utilizing a browser that prohibits file system linking, or if the user is operating over a VPN outside of the more permissive "Local Intranet" zone.

All of this is discusses in the linked article.

Good luck!