# stored db url does not echo image

Tags: php, mysql, jpeg

I have a MySQL db with a table, that has the following field:

txtProductBowlImage: example " C:\BowlPhotos\Thumbs\MapleTi07-030tmb.jpg"

I want to use the data in that field to produce an image that I can print to a text file.

I read the data then try to echo it to the screen...and I see a small icon, but no image.

Here's the code:

```
    <?php
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","xxxxxxx","zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("scwdb", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblsplintersbowlinventory WHERE txtVenue = 'Shoreline'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['intProductID'] . " " . $row['txtProductBowlCode'] . " " . $row['txtProductBowlImage'] . "]";
  echo "<br />";
  echo "<br />";
  echo 'txtProductBowlImage: ' . $row['txtProductBowlImage'];
  echo "<br />";
  $img = $row['txtProductBowlImage'];
  echo '...............$img: ' . $img;
  echo "<br />";
  echo "<img src=" . $img . ">";
  echo "<img src='C://BowlPhotos//Thumbs//Ash07-013_btmb.jpg'>";
  echo "<img src='Ash07-013_btmb.jpg'>";
  echo "<br />";
  echo "==================";
  echo "<br />";
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Note that I try 3 times to show an image:
1: using the url from the db and putting it in an echo statement
   this url uses the '\' separater in the data.
2: imbedding a sample of the actual text path and filename in an echo statement
   this url uses the '/' separater in the url.
3: imbedding only the filename, no path, in an echo statement

When I run this, I get the following output:

[image]

Echo #1 & #2 produce the icon, echo #3 shows a local copy of the image in the same folder as the php.

From this it appears that it is the path that is not being used, either with the '\' or '/' separater.

I assume the '\' may be seen as an escape, but why doesn't the url with the '/' work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, with JonOsterman's greatly appreciated aid, the final working code is:

```
    <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","Madge1938");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("scwdb", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblsplintersbowlinventory WHERE txtVenue = 'Shoreline'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row;
echo "<span>" . $row['intProductID'] . " " . $row['txtProductBowlCode'] . " " . $row['txtProductBowlImage'] . "</span>";
echo "<br />";
$img = $row['txtProductBowlImage'];
echo "<span> Original img: " . $img . " </span>";
$img = str_replace('\\', '/', $img);
echo "<br />";
$img = str_replace('C:/BowlPhotos/Thumbs/', 'Thumbs/', $img);
echo "<span>Folder img: " . $img . " </span>";
echo '<img src="' . $img . '">';
echo "<br />";
$img = str_replace('Thumbs/', '', $img);
echo "<span>Local img: " . $img . " </span>";
echo '<img src="' . $img . '">';
echo "<br />";
echo "<span>done</span><br />";
}

mysql_close($con);
?
```

There were a number of changes, but the biggest surprise was that the php could not open a folder not in the same folder or a sub folder of the php file! When I moved the entire folder to a sub of the php folder, the code above runs!

Also, as seen above, the HTML does not need a "file:///" for a local file...

And I should mention, this is intended to run only on my local server - not on the web. It is just for my own use to keep track of the wood bowls I make and sell.

Again, many thanks to Jon...

Answer (score 1):

All below is wrong seeing as ["Linking to local resources is disabled in all modern browsers due to security restrictions"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5246334/677331)

> To link to a **local** image you use the format
>
> ```
> <img src='file:///C:/path/to/image/pic.jpg'>
> ```
>
> You can replace the backslashes with forward slashes using
>
> ```
> $img = str_replace('\\', '/', $row['txtProductBowlImage']);
> ```
>
> Now you can add the `file:///` and the single quotes around the path
>   like so
>
> ```
> echo "<img src='file:///" . $img . "'>";
> ```
>
> With double quotes you could skip the dot operator to append strings
>   and use
>
> ```
> echo "<img src='file:///$img'>";
> ```
>
> The dollar `$img` will be recognized as a variable

Comment: I see that - made the change but it still doesn't show the image, just the icon. I even tried echoing the HTML you show, that does the same thing...

Comment: Try adding`file:///` before the path.
So it's <img src='file:///C:/BowlPhotos/Thumbs/MapleTi07-030tmb.jpg'>
But,  you do know that the path is of a local file? It is only visible to you who has the image in that location.

Comment: That doesn't work either... and this will be a local script, I will use it to print ID cards for each bowl.

Comment: Did you note that you have to replace backslashes with forward slashes? You can do it with the str_replace function.

$img = str_replace('\\', '/', $img);
You can do it in one line with
$img = str_replace('\\', '/', $row['txtProductBowlImage']);

Comment: Yeah, I knew the "\" was part of the problem and I need to make that change - I was trying it both ways since neither worked...I just added that to the code, and ran it. The change is made, but it still just gives me the icon.

Comment: What does the broken icon HTML look like?

I can see it just fine in all browsers with `<img src='file:///C:/path/to/image/KpFDc.jpg'>`
given that the image exists there of course

Comment: Looking at the source I see this: 354 MapleTi07-030 C:\BowlPhotos\Thumbs\MapleTi07-030tmb.jpg]<br /><br />txtProductBowlImage: C:\BowlPhotos\Thumbs\MapleTi07-030tmb.jpg<br />...............$img: C:/BowlPhotos/Thumbs/MapleTi07-030tmb.jpg<br /><img src='C:/BowlPhotos/Thumbs/MapleTi07-030tmb.jpg'><img src='file:///C:\BowlPhotos\Thumbs\MapleTi07-030tmb.jpg'><img src='file:///C:/BowlPhotos/Thumbs/MapleTi07-030tmb.jpg'><img src='C://BowlPhotos//Thumbs//Ash07-013_btmb.jpg'><img src='Ash07-013_btmb.jpg'><br />==================<br />

Comment: And yes, I just checked, the file:///C:\BowlPhotos\Thumbs\MapleTi07-030tmb.jpg command does bring up the actual image. Make that file:///C:/BowlPhotos/Thumbs/MapleTi07-030tmb.jpg...:)

Comment: Delete all the other attempts at printing the image except the one with `file:///` and the forward slashes, since they won't display anyway.

Comment: OK, that gives me  $img = $row['txtProductBowlImage'];
  $img = str_replace('\\', '/', $img);
  echo "<img src='file:///" . $img . "'>";
  
  And the same result.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19061/discussion-between-stephen-and-jonosterman)

Answer (score 0):

It seams your trying to get a file from your local computer. So you have to run a webserver that hadle php

You might be trying to read an image where the server dont have acess.

try to place the file with your html or php file

Comment: And use a path relative to your web server root directory not the hard drive