# How to open a windows folder when clicking on some link on a HTML page using PHP

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me how to open a windows folder by clicking on href link in php page? I'm unaware of this concept and even no idea..Even no related posts in stackoverflow too. Somebody help..thanks in advance..

Tried this but went vain..

```
<a href="file:///D:/Tools/">Open folder</a>
```

Comment: what you supposed to do with that?

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246292/open-local-folder-from-link

Comment: @Mohammad Faisal Our company required to search files from browser which displays path of it. Until that i have done my job..now they added a requirement to open the desired folder from the path in browser.kindly help

Comment: @Jenz so we cannot achieve this functionality for security reasons right? ok can we copy the path to clipboard atleast? any ideas on it?

Comment: Got "copy to clipboard" from http://jsfiddle.net/Vr4Ky/180/ thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use an form input instead.

```
<body>
<form>
<input type="file">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi..from output i need to open a windows explorer. Output iam printing a filepath from my php code..how can i achieve this?

Comment: Some browsers will not allow that for security reasons, but here is an article of how to work around the problem with javascript.. [Accessing Filepath in HTML](http://rattomago.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/accessing-filepath-in-html-input-element-via-javascript/)