# Perl Redirect CGI File To A "file://" Address

Tags: perl, redirect, location, cgi

I am a newbie Perl programmer so please go easy on me. Is there any way to remotely redirect a page from calling a perl .cgi file to another page file? The user will click a link which leads to a .cgi file. The .cgi file then will redirect the user to a "file://" location. The purpose is to download a file in another server after logging for click count.

The code below works for "http://" addresses, but how do I get it to work with "file://" addresses?

```
#!C:\Strawberry\perl\bin

use strict;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
my $page = new CGI;
# print header and start the markup output

print "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n";
print $page->header( "text/html" );
print $page->start_html( "CGI Environment" );

print "Hello world! ";
print "Press the Enter key to exit.\n";

my $url="file://location_of_file";
my $t=1; # time until redirect activates
print "<META HTTP-EQUIV=refresh CONTENT=\"$t;URL=$url\">\n";


print $page->end_html;

# end code
```

Is this a good approach? Is there a better approach? Please help. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: If the file is on a server, file:// won't be able to get out anyway, or are you talking about a network share when you say server?

Answer (score 2):

This is not permitted for security reasons. All browsers (that I know of) will refuse a meta redirect from an http:// URL to a file:// URL. The same restriction applies to 30x server redirects. See the [Redirect Restrictions section of the Browser Security Handbook](https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Redirection_restrictions) for more information.

Comment: Is there a way to call a "file://" url from Perl?

Comment: If you want to open a file local to the server than just use `open`. If you want to open a file on the client, then no. For me it looks like you don't understand the concepts how the web works, which has nothing to do with Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most useful way would be by using '.url' files (static or dynamically generated), as explained nicely in [JFish222's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14249649/4519961)

Otherwise, I'm afraid you'd be stuck with elevating privileges (strongly browser dependent), or playing with browser extensions etc..