# HTML Link not working?

Tags: html, node.js, pug, ejs

I'm running this jade-based app locally and I've been trying to include a ejs file in it but I was unsuccessful. So I tried to convert my ejs file to jade and again my several attempts failed.

So I thought about just creating a HTML link that takes me to the ejs page on click. Problem is when I click it, nothing happens.

Here's how I made the link:

```
<a href="file:///home/ghanem/Documents/drywall-master/views/account/el.ejs">My Link</a>.
```

Comment: Please note that HTML will be parsed when used in a question unless you post it as code.

Comment: Check you link first: file:///home/ghanem/Documents/drywall-master/views/account/el.ejs

Comment: When I type "file:///home/ghanem/Documents/drywall-master/views/account/el.ejs" in my browser I get redirected to the file. But strangely enough the html link doesn't take me anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Linking to local resources is disabled in all modern browsers due to security restrictions.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246292/open-local-folder-from-link/5246334#5246334) answers for more details.

Answer (score -1):

check if the link is really `file:///`
or you can use double dot notation in your link

example:

`../views/account/el.js`

Hope it helps