# R shiny: Open a folder on my computer through a link

Tags: r, shiny

I want to have a link in my shiny app opening a folder on my local computer. So if I click the link I want to see `C:/Testfolder` in a new windows explorer window. However my so far tested links don't work:

```
a("click on me",target="_blank",href="C:/Testfolder")
a("click on me",target="_blank",href="file:///C:/Testfolder")
```

Comment: It seems that this should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246292/open-local-folder-from-link