# how to open a folder than close IE automatically

Tags: html, internet-explorer

i'd like to ask a question.

I have a html page, i'd like that when this html page is opened(or directed), it will open a folder(in local with Explorer) then close IE automatically.is it possible?

thank u very much

best regards

martin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open local folder from link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246292/open-local-folder-from-link)