# Open local pdf file from a local html file

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, local

I am working in a simple html application which is expected to run in IE8 and above, Chrome browsers. The html application is launched from a desktop shortcut and it will open in the default browser as shown below,

[image]

Note: The path of the html file is local path.

To avoid security issues related in loading scripts, I have added the "Mark of the Web" in my application and it works great.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
```

The issue I am facing now is, opening a help file (.pdf) which is in the same location as html file throws "Access Denied" error.

Options I have tried:

a. Referred the help file path in the HTML tab and it did not work

```
<a href="help.pdf" class="help pull-right" target="_blank">Help</a>
```

a. On the above link click , set the window.location as shown below,

```
window.location = 'help.pdf' //access denied error
```

I have also referred several answers in stackoverflow say for example:
[How can I create a link to a local file on a locally-run web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page)
but none of them worked for me.

**Expectation:**

Open a local pdf file from a link in local html file. Is it possible? Let me know your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at this one?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246292/open-local-folder-from-link/5246334#5246334

Comment: @whipdancer, the link you provided was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this out, just change location of ur pdf file into below href ..., better put thm in a seperate folder ie the html and pdf file that u wanna download.

```html
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="someID" >continue</a>
<script>
$('a#someID').attr({target: '_blank', 
                    href  : 'http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs124/downloads/javanotes6-linked.pdf'});
  
  // give the location of ur file... in href
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cannot put the pdf in a separate location. The computers where I am deploying the html application does not have any internet connection. The .pdf file should remain in the same location as html file.

Comment: yeah, create any folder in desktop or in any drive , then keep ur pdf file and html, once it is done , i have given my own location ie an http location, u try to change it as ur file name alone like this 'code'                                                                  $('a#someID').attr({target: '_blank', 
                    href  : ' filename.pdf ' });

Comment: I tried the same using javascript (as I don't use jquery in this project) and it throws Access Denied error in browser.

Comment: <a href=javascript:downloadme('javanotes6-linked.pdf'); >Download this pdf</a>

<script>
 function downloadme(x){
    winObj = window.open(x,'','left=10000,screenX=10000');
    winObj.document.execCommand('SaveAs','true','download.pdf');

    winObj.close();
 }
 </script>