# How to open a pdf document on click of hyper link in datatables js grid

Tags: javascript, file, pdf

I want to open a PDF document on click of a hyper link in DataTables grid column.
Please help.

This function is called on a button click just for test but js error: Access denied.

```
function openPDF() {
   window.open("file:///D:/test.pdf", "_blank", "");
}
```

Comment: I know I have tried everything but the problem is Access denied error from js... I have checked VS temp folder , Windows temp folder permissions and set it to everyone full access but still access denied

Comment: You are aware that browsers cant access the local file system right.

Comment: any other option to open a pdf file located at local machine or server ?

Comment: I see your using Windows. Heres a barebones webserver you can host your website on so you can make your link work. https://www.cesanta.com/products/binary

Comment: Ok that means it will work on server. right ?

Comment: If you set the url correctly yes it will.

Comment: This helped me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35615627/open-local-pdf-file-from-a-local-html-file