# can jquery open a local directory path? Can chrome.fileSystem work with jquery for this solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

It looks like javascript/jquery can only open up files at a specific filepath and not display the directory itself. is there a way i can open a directory with jquery?
when i go to open a filepath i get nothing but `about:blank` what i need it to display is in the screenshot below.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".folder").click(function() {
      window.open('file:///C:/Users/ALilland/Documents/test/');
    });
});
```

I am trying to open this directory, my tested browser is google chrome, therefore I have heard there should be a way. I have heard of something called chrome.fileSystem but does this work with javascript? or is it exclusive to chrome applications?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open local folder from link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246292/open-local-folder-from-link)

Answer (score -1):

Your web browser will not allow you to access the local file system if you navigate using the HTTP(S) protocol. This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246292/open-local-folder-from-link).

Comment: Not really an answer. Should have just been marked duplicate.

Comment: You did not answer my question nor is it a duplicate, my question is in the context of the Google API

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I assumed you were developing a regular web page. You didn't mention that you were writing a Chrome App.