# html link open directory in MVC and IE

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am Using Asp.Net MVC. I need use a link to open network drive path as well as normal url (html file path).

I have tried by using 
" `<a href="path" ></a>` " but not working.

Please help me.

Comment: can you put sample path here

Comment: file:///C:\Test\tt.txt

Comment: for local files it works but for network path use \\ip-or-computer-name\path

Comment: for me , even local files not working... is there any IE settings or permission issues ?

Comment: I dont think, did you recieved any error?

Comment: No error... but not opens the path

Comment: According to the following post, it appears to be working that way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246292/open-local-folder-from-link/5246334#5246334