# Open File Explorer window from JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to open a File Explorer from JavaScript. I tried using window.open("FolderPath"), it works fine but along with the file explorer it also opens a new web browser tab.

Is there a way to just open the File explorer?

Comment: Do you want the user to select a file or just open the explorer? What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: I think it may be helpful if you could give a little more information.  Why do you need to open the file explorer?  Do you want your user to pick a file to upload or be used in your app or what?  Also, window.open opens a url, if you use folder path you would need it to be used with a url like `file:///`, if you ran that on a webserver, it would look for the file relative to where you are and probably not find it.

Comment: So here's the thing, I have a button in my webpage which should just open a file explorer in a specific folder path and do nothing further, no uploads or file selects, so I cannot use a <input type=file .. /> 

For this purpose when I use the window.open("FilePathUrl"), it opens a tab along with the file explorer. So I'm just wondering if there is a way to just open the file explorer.

I'm using IE, I have used file:// along with the folder path.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In general, allowing javascript to run programs is a big no-no.

See [this related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246292/open-local-folder-from-link)

Answer (score 0):

well I don't have clear the question but I think that you can use a input with the type equals to file

```
<input type="file" id="someID" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't want to select a file. I just to open a regular File explorer.