# opening a shared local folder(C drive or D Drive etc..) from a JSP deployed in a tomcat server

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee

Can you help me on opening local drive(which is a shared drive) C:,D: etc from a JSP installed in the tomcat in other machine or any other suggestion to achieve the same

I tried the following different things and none of it was worked.I tried putting the window.open in the href also but that doesn't work as well.

```
 window.open('file://'+hostname+'/C:','Results','width=500,height=500');
```

window.open("file://mymechine name/C$"); 
window.open('file:///C:/RIT_Results')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most browsers no longer supports opening of local folders/files from remote domains for security reasons.

Here are some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5246334/6785649) about this issue as well.

You will have to create additional interfaces to allow the clients to interact with the folders if you choose to proceed from here on.

Comment: Cheers. Glad it help.