# Including html anchor tags in the 'Yield' of the Bottle framework

Tags: python, function, bottle

Newly playing around with the Bottle framework in python.

I'm trying to include an anchor tag that links to a local folder in the 'Yield' component of the bottle framework.

I keep getting an error when I try to include anchor   tags in the Yield statement

Snippet of code is below:

```
 from bottle import Bottle,run

 app = Bottle()

 @app.route('/conn')
 def conn():
     yield '<center> <p>Here is the <a href="file:///C:\Programs\Documents">Connection Folder </a>  </p> </center>'
```

The above code is not running, I get an error saying 'SyntaxError'. I expected to get a result whereby on connection the initial webpage yields to a new webpage with the statement 'Here is the connection folder' (where the string Connection Folder is a link to the local folder)

EDIT 1:
I have now gotten the code to work by doing this:

```
 from bottle import Bottle,run

 app = Bottle()

 @app.route('/conn')
 def conn():
     yield '<center> <p>Here is the <a href="file:///C:\\Programs\\Documents">Connection Folder </a>  </p> </center>'
```

That is by adding double slashes

Now my question now is that the link is not opening up the required folder, is there anything I should add to the code above?

Comment: I just tested your code and didn't get any errors.  Can you be more specific on what the error is that you are getting?

Comment: Keep in mind I had to add `run(app)` at the bottom.

Comment: @eatmeimadanish I get an error saying "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position : truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: @eatmeimadanish Please see my new edit above.

Comment: Backslashes are special characters in Python strings. You can either escape them (as you discovered), or, alternatively, use a [raw string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081708/593047) by prepending `r`. E.g. `yield r'<center> ... "file:///C:\Programs\Documents"...'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out an answer to my question:

1) The error of SyntaxError was sorted by doing either of these two:
  Using either double back slashes or single forward slash worked.

2) I then encountered another challenge where the link could not access a local folder due to the security setups of Chrome.

I worked around this by looking at this post: [Open local folder from link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246292/open-local-folder-from-link)