# How to display files from the local project on HTML web site?

Tags: html, list, directory, filereader, web-development-server

I am new in development and I am wondering is there any way that I can display content of the folder on the web page. For an example.. 
https://media.prod.mdn.mozit.cloud/attachments/2014/11/11/9231/c5b2b5fba968bc6d3d896b39409c889e/file-structure.png 
structure of my code looks like this. 
I want to be able to display the files from img folder on website.
User should be able to click on them and open them in browser.

Comment: you can simply run `python -m http.server` in your terminal (with python3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this but I don't think it would be wise due to security to your network. There is a chrome extension but this won't work for users who don't have it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246292/open-local-folder-from-link) is a very similar, if not the same, question which explains why you shouldn't do it and an answer below which explains how to do it.

Bare in mind, it will always work for you as your directories are local and accessed internally.