# Open folder in new window with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

To open a popup window with a given url I use:

```
$("#OpenFolder").click(function () {
  var url = "https://stackoverflow.com";
  windowObjectReference = window.open(url, "ModulesList", "popup");
})
```

and

```
<button id="OpenFolder">OpenFolder</button>
```

Now I would like to open a folder located on the computer (where my script is) to have the possibility to select a file.
What should be url (the path is something like /home/...) ?
Thanks

Comment: You can't do this solely programmatically - due to security issues the browser won't let you. There has to be some input from the user to specify the folder/file otherwise you could access anyone's files on their computer. For that you can use the [`FileReader API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar issue previously asked. You can reference it for more info.

[Open local folder from link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5246292/17042216)