# Windows file explorer address bar path chooser with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, windows, filepicker

I want to create a fonction or input type: file who open windows file explorer with a given path in the address bar.

I mean I have a button, onclick it trigger windows file explorer using input:file and pass a given url via props to the address bar.

So with this I can open a distant folder with windows file explorer.

Any solution ?

I try a lot a thinks and package from web but none did that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open local folder from link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246292/open-local-folder-from-link)

Comment: *I try a lot* - since it's not possible, not sure what "thinks and packages from web" you actually tried